# How to replace environment variable with value in ansible variable

Tags: ansible

I have a JSON object of files and the destinations they need to be symlinked moved to. I would like to be able to have environment variables in the destinations and have them evaluated to know where they should be moved to. I'm attempting to do a `regex_search` with a `lookup`, but it isn't giving me the desired result.

Here is the json:

dotfiles.json

```json
{
  "mac": [
    {
      "name": ".gitconfig",
      "destination": "$HOME/"
    }
  ]
}
```

playbook: ansible/bootstrap.yaml

```yaml
---
- name: "Bootstrapping Machine"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  ignore_errors: true
  vars:
    dotfiles: "{{ lookup('file', '../dotfiles.json') | from_json }}"
  roles:
    - role: "MacOSX"
      when: "ansible_distribution == 'MacOSX'"
```

tasks: ansible/roles/MacOSX/tasks/main.yaml

```yaml
- name: Symlink dotfiles
  ansible.builtin.file:
      src: "../../../dotfiles/{{ item.name }}"
      dest: "{{ destination  }}"
      state: link
  vars:
    destination: "{{ item.destination | regex_replace('\\$\\w+', lookup('env', '\\1')) }}"
  with_items: "{{ dotfiles.mac | list }}"
```

The `destination` variable evaluates to `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a quick and dirty fix of your original idea. This will only work if you target localhost (as lookups only run on localhost) hence will fail for a remote target (as the env var will be gathered for the current user on your local environment).

Moreover, the regexes/replace/lookups will probably fail as soon as you introduce more than one env var in your string(s). But at least you get a first working example for your particular situation and can build over it.

The following example playbook (using the same json file as in your question):

```yaml
- name: "Replace dollar env var with local env value"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    dotfiles: "{{ lookup('file', 'dotfiles.json') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Replace dollar env var with local env value
      vars:
        env_var: >-
          {{ item.destination | regex_replace('\$(\w+)/', '\1') }}
        destination: >-
          {{ item.destination | regex_replace('\$\w+[^/]', lookup('env', env_var)) }}{{ item.name }}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ destination }}"
      loop: "{{ dotfiles.mac }}"
```

Gives (username redacted)

```
$ ansible-playbook bootstrap.yml

PLAY [Replace dollar env var with local env value] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Replace dollar env var with local env value] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': '.gitconfig', 'destination': '$HOME/'}) => {
    "msg": "/home/somelocaluser/.gitconfig"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```